# How to know if a form field is translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation, symfony-2.1

Is there a shortcut to know if an entity field has the `@Gedmo\Translatable` property set, let say when rendering a form, or displaying entity values ?

For example, having this field :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
private $name;
```

While displaying the entity, I'd like to know if a field is translatable, by doing something like this (pseudo-code idea of what it could be or look like in **twig** templates)

```
{% entity.title in entity.translatable.fields %}
```

***Note :** The real idea behind this is to automatically display a marker on translatable form field.*

- [Translatable Behavior extension for Doctrine2](http://gediminasm.org/article/translatable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your entity repository, assuming you extend the TranslationRepository, you could create a custom function that retrieves fields that have translations.  You could create a custom method in your repository along the lines of

```
use use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository;

class MyEntityRepository extends TranslationRepository 
{

     public function getTranslatableFieldsByClass($className)
     {
            $translationMeta = $this->getClassMetadata();

            $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('trans.field')
                ->from($translationMeta->rootEntityName, 'trans')
                ->where('trans.objectClass = :entityClass')
                ->groupBy('trans.field');

            $q = $qb->getQuery();

            $data = $q->execute(
                array('entityClass' => $className),
                Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY
            );

            return (array) $data;
     }
}
```

Then load the results into your template, and use a similar 'in' clause like you have mentioned above.

```
$translatableFields = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyTranslatableEntity')->getTranslatableFieldsByClass(get_class($myTranslatableEntity));
```

Comment: Neat, but in case I have many translatable Entities (10+), this seems to be such a repetitive task.
I also forgot to mention I have an entity for each translation, maybe this way I could avoid getting the fields by Class ? What do you think ? I'm trying it today.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't have much experience with the translation extension, as I created my answer by looking at the bundle's source.  I think your answer would be to create a twig extension which runs the above query, but entity-agnostic.  You should be able to get the translation metadata based on the classname of the entity passed through the twig extension.

Comment: Good idea ! Thanks for taking the time Mike, helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Twig extension:

```
class TranslatableTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
/**
 * @var ObjectManager
 */
private $om;

/**
 * @var TranslatableListener
 */
private $listener;

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $om
 */
public function __construct(ObjectManager $om, TranslatableListener $listener )
{
    $this->om = $om;
    $this->listener = $listener;
}

private function isTranslatableField($object, $name)
{
    $config = $this->listener->getConfiguration($this->om, get_class($object));

    if (isset($config['fields']) && in_array($name, $config['fields']) ) 
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    if ( $form->getParent() == null )
        return;

    if ( is_object($form->getParent()->getData())) {
        if ( $this->isTranslatableField($form->getParent()->getData(),    $form->getName()) )
            $view->vars['field_translatable'] = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the name of the type being extended.
 *
 * @return string The name of the type being extended
 */
public function getExtendedType()
{
    return 'field';
}
}
```

Load this extension as follows:

```
my_extension.translatable_type_extension:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension\TranslatableTypeExtension
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@gedmo.listener.translatable"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, alias: field }
```

In your twig templates you could use something like this:

```
{% if field_translatable is defined and field_translatable %} Translatable field {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement altough accepted answer won't work for me since it relies on already translated fields. Since I want it even if db is empty I came up with solution based on Gedmo ExtensionMetadataFactory.  (solution is written on SF 2.8 and PHP 7.1)

```
 [...]

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener;

/**
 * Helper Class TranslatableFieldsHelper - allow to get array of translatable fields for given entity class.
 *
 * @package [...]
 * @author [...]
 */
class TranslatableFieldsHelper
{
    /**
     * @var TranslatableListener
     */
    protected $listener;
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * TranslatableFieldsHelper constructor.
     * @param TranslatableListener $listener
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatableListener $listener, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->listener = $listener;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Get translatable fields list of given class
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTranslatableFields(string $class): array
    {
        $config = $this->listener->getConfiguration($this->em, $class);

        return $config && isset($config['fields']) && is_array($config['fields']) ? $config['fields'] : [];
    }
}
```

After implementing this class simply register it as service:

```
_alias_:
    class: _class_
    arguments: ['@stof_doctrine_extensions.listener.translatable', '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
```

And use it:

```
$this->container->get(__alias__)->getTranslatableFields(__your_entity_class__);
```

EDIT:

Comment: After writing this, realised that chris answer is basicly the same solution. Nevertheless decided to keep it, in case some1 needs it :)